# Elastic Search query for array in index

Tags: elasticsearch

i have index (default schema) which contains field "personnel", and this field is an array.

in index are two object:

```
{"took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.8630463,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "warehouse",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "order": 2,
          "status": "done",
          "personnel": [
            {
              "name": "mike",
              "function": "packer"
            },
            {
              "name": "henry",
              "function": "checker"
            } ] }
      },
      {
        "_index": "warehouse",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8630463,
        "_source": {
          "order": 1,
          "status": "done",
          "personnel": [
            {
              "name": "jon",
              "function": "packer"
            },
            {
              "name": "mike",
              "function": "checker"
            }
 ] } } ] } }
```

and i want query it to get *order* where status is done and person which packed this order is a mike.

I trey a lot of queries, but i always get two orders because mike exist in both orders (witch different function)

example  query:

```
{"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "status": "done"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "personnel.name": "mike"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "personnel.function": "packer"
                                }
            } ] } } ] } } }
```

my question is how prepare query to return me only one order, where mike is packer

Comment: Here are your answers : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

Comment: ok, this is it what i need, thank you :)... but this create for me new problem, and maybe you know that it's possible for my old bool query to coexist with the nested query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my answer is just a guess since your dont provide a description of the problems you are encountering. But you query with the nested part should be like that :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "status": "done"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "personnel",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "personnel.name": "mike"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "personnel.function": "packer"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need now, thank you very much and I apologize for non-specific information